# Scroll page to hash position on page reload - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website with angularJS and using twitter bootstrap for UI. I have some hash `Ids` associated with certain section, so that when user click on navigation, page scrolls down to that section. And its working fine for me.

Here the site link:  https://powerful-cliffs-1105.herokuapp.com/about

Now in about page. I have right navigation which scrolls page to specific position. But when i reload that page, page starts from top and doesn't scroll down to `hash` position, like https://powerful-cliffs-1105.herokuapp.com/about#management

There are two solutions for the above problem:

1. Either remove hash tag from URL when we reload that page.
2. Scroll page to particular(hash) section on page reload.

Since i am still learning angularJS, i am unable to find any concrete solution of above problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution? because it appears that the sample page you posted in the question is working correctly now.

Comment: @AndrewCounts: Yes, now i changed my code (also upload it to provided link) using javascript `scroll` method. But unfortunately, `$anchorScroll` doesn't work as expected for me while reloading the page. Maybe DOM isn't ready when it called. If you have a solution with angular, then i love to implement it. Have a look at the answer for approach which i used now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) service.

The problem here, is that Angular loads the **about** content dinamically, so when you have the **hash** you don't have the content ready. `$anchorScroll` tracks the hash and scroll it for you.

```
// Just borrow from your code    
angular.module('aboutController', []).controller('aboutController',['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll', 
    function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {

  $scope.isActive = function(route){
     return route === $location.hash();
  }

  $anchorScroll();
}]);
```

## Edit 31/12:

Since Mohit (the creator of the question) said that my solution didn't work for him, I decided to download the code and work locally. My solution worked locally, which made me scrach my head, but I'd like to point a few editions in the code that probably (or most probably not) can solve the issue.

### Move the scripts to the bottom of the page (index.html)

```
<!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
  <div class="body" ng-view></div>

  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer ng-include="'views/footer.html'"></footer>

  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="js/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

  <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM CONTROLLERS -->
  <script src="js/controllers/home.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/about.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/contact.js"></script>

  <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM FACTORIES -->
  <script src="js/services/contact.js"></script>

  <!-- UTILITY FILE -->
  <script src="js/utils/util.js"></script>

  <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM ROUTES AND APP -->
  <script src="js/route-provider.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

### Remove/comment, for now, the html5Mode (route-provider.js)

```
// $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and append `/#/` before accessing the URLs, [like this](https://powerful-cliffs-1105.herokuapp.com/#/about#management)

### Put a timeout

This is by far the one I don't suggest, but certainly you can give a shot

```
$timeout(function() {
    $anchorScroll(); 
}, 0)
```

Comment: @Rigoti: You are right but unfortunately this doesn't work when i reload the content. When i add `$anchorScroll`, it does nothing when i reload the page.

Comment: @MohitPandey Bit late here, I can't guess what could be wrong here,  I already had this issue and this solved for me. Have you tried moving your scripts to the bottom of your `<body>`?

Comment: @Rigoti: Thanks, moving script files to the bottom of `<body>` do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use a directive and watch the scope value into it :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['LocalStorageModule']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [ '$scope', 'localStorageService', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  if(localStorageService.isSupported) {
    $scope.util = localStorageService.get('anchor');
    console.log(localStorageService.get('anchor'));
  }
  else{
    $scope.util = "third";
  }

  $scope.moveTo = function(anchor){
    console.log('controller anchor value:', anchor);
    $scope.util = anchor;
    if(localStorageService.isSupported) {
      localStorageService.set('anchor', anchor);
    }
  };


}]);

app.directive('scrollToAnchor', ['$location', '$anchorScroll', function($location, $anchorScroll){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      anchor: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element){
        scope.$watch('anchor', function(){
          $location.hash(scope.anchor);
          $anchorScroll();
          console.log('directive anchor value:', scope.anchor);
        });
    }
  };
}]);
```

I don't know if it's the best way but you need to have your dom rendered before scrolling to the element.

here the plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/niFzeX7XAJVNzDoD0CXa?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. I don't know whether its a best solution or not but it definitely provide a solution using angular. Also, i think that there might be a solution available without using localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

After investing more time in angularJS, i discovered `$anchorScroll` will need to work as @Rigoti said. But somehow it didn't work for me.

Alternatively, i discover that we can create our own method using factories/services or we can also create a separate class/object like utility file which can then be used in angular module. 
So i create a util file and add a method to provide smooth scrolling using this great fiddle by brettdewoody http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/y65G5/

After that i modified my code, so that i can access that method and call it.

**about.js**

```
angular.module('aboutController', []).controller('aboutController',['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {

    // create local instance of utility object
    $scope.util = util;

    // move scroll position to passed id
    $scope.moveTo = function(id){
        // set hash location to clicked id so that isActive class is added to it.
        $location.hash(id);
        // scroll to element id
        $scope.util.scrollTo(id);
    }

    // set active class to right hand navigation on route change
    $scope.isActive = function(route){
        return route === $location.hash();
    }

    // if hash is available, scroll to hash position on page reload
    //$anchorScroll();
    if(!$scope.util.isNull($location.hash()))
        $scope.util.scrollTo($location.hash());

}]);
```

**util.js**

```
/**
 * Created by admin on 22/12/14.
 */

var util = {
    scrollTo: function(id) {

        // This scrolling function
        // is from http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript

        var startY = currentYPosition();
        var stopY = elmYPosition(id);
        var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
        if (distance < 100) {
            scrollTo(0, stopY);
            return;
        }
        var speed = Math.round(distance / 100);
        if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
        var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
        var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
        var timer = 0;
        if (stopY > startY) {
            for (var i = startY; i < stopY; i += step) {
                setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, " + leapY + ")", timer * speed);
                leapY += step;
                if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY;
                timer++;
            }
            return;
        }
        for (var i = startY; i > stopY; i -= step) {
            setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, " + leapY + ")", timer * speed);
            leapY -= step;
            if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY;
            timer++;
        }

        function currentYPosition() {
            // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
            // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
            if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
            if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
            return 0;
        }

        function elmYPosition(id) {
            var elm = document.getElementById(id);
            var y = elm.offsetTop;
            var node = elm;
            while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
                node = node.offsetParent;
                y += node.offsetTop;
            }
            return y;
        }
    },
    isNull: function (o) {
        return angular.isUndefined(o) || o === null || o === '';
    }
}
```

**about.html**

```
<li><a ng-class="{active:isActive('about')}" ng-click="moveTo('about')">About</a></li>
<li><a ng-class="{active:isActive('keraleeyam')}" ng-click="moveTo('keraleeyam')">Keraleeyam Ayurveda</a></li>
<li><a ng-class="{active:isActive('management')}" ng-click="moveTo('management')">Management</a></li>
<li><a ng-class="{active:isActive('treatment')}" ng-click="moveTo('treatment')">Panchakarma Treatment</a></li>
```

And, it worked for me :). I also made changes to live URL so that you can look into it.

**NOTE:** I am still waiting for a solution using `$anchorScroll` method. So please help me if you found anything which i missed.